# Armature rig moving random areas of my mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I've built a low Polly character and I'm now trying to rig it for animations.

I followed a guide and the guide told me to use auto normalize to prevent the problem I'm having now but it doesn't seem to work, and its nothing to do with the weight painting seen as I've repainted it already thinking this was the problem, but when I rotate the upper arm bone it moves some vertices of the mesh on the hand on the other side this is the same problem with the opposite arm bone as well where it moves some vertices on the opposite hand.

As far as I can tell I cant see the weight painting on the arms showing up any where near the hands.
And if your wondering how I connected the armature and mesh together I selected them and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> and used with automatic weights in case that's important.

As a side note I'm only starting to learn rigging and weight painting but I have been using blender for a while now for modelling .

Comment: maybe try to recalculate the normals before parenting, if it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ah that was it thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate the normals in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>) and parent again